# PHP - Function Inside 2d Array

Tags: php

I have a 2d array that includes an anonymous function that I would like to execute.  For some reason I'm drawing a blank on how to call the function.

The following with throw an error:

```
$someArray[] = ['somevalue', function () {echo "test function";}];
$someArray[0][1]();
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

If I do the following, it will work

```
$someFunc = $someArray[0][1];
$someFunc();
```

Comment: What you want must be working as of 5.4 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function inside an array, use this:

```
call_user_func($someArray[0][1], $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

Or this:

```
call_user_func_array($someArray[0][1], array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to PHP 5.4 calling a function like this does not work.

If you absolutely have to be able to do this then you will have to upgrade to PHP 5.4 or greater.

In older versions of PHP you have to dereference the closure (get it out of the array) before using it.